# Twit button with prepopulated text in data-text attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I'm trying to do a random quote generator page for a FreeCodeCamp project, my problem here is that I can't make a prepopulated twit button with the text of the quote. Here comes the code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com//intent/tweet?" class="twitter-share-button" data-size="small" data-dnt="true" data-show-count="false" data-text="hello">Tweet</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The twitter API has an attribute called data-text that you can use to set some prepopulated text when you press the twit button, and I want to change that property with a jQuery function like this:

```
function getNewQuote(){
$.ajax({url: "https://random-quote-generator.herokuapp.com/api/quotes/random", success: function(result){
$(".randomQuote").html(result.quote);
$(".twitter-share-button").prop('data-text', result.quote);
$(".randomAuthor").html(result.author);
}});
}
```

The problem is that this property doesn't changes and the twit never gets populated with the randome quote that I get from the API. If you need it you can find full code in my codepen: https://codepen.io/VictorGE/pen/eVwbEY

I have this codepen as an example too, but I prefer to use my own way to solve this: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/ONjoLe

¡Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Don't use `.prop` - this should be either `.attr("data-text", result.quote)` or `.data("text", result.quote)` - note that using `.data()` is preferred but won't "change" your html if that's what you're expecting.

Comment: I added `console.log($(".twitter-share-button").prop('data-text'));` to your `getNewQuote()` and it shows it changing it fine.

Comment: The problem is that your button `.twitter-share-button` is *not* the `tweet` button you see at the bottom - it's a different button.  Change the caption of your button from "tweet" to "do it" and you'll see - that's not your button.

Comment: `https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js` is adding an iframe for the social media tweets and you're not updating those widgets, you're updating your (now) hidden button.

Comment: Then, is there any possible way to change that property with the current quote that is showing in the page?